# Vagrant Error, The box failed to unpackage properly

Tags: database, vb.net, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a question for help that I could not find on any of these topics already.

I am trying to implement vagrant against my pre-existing virtual box. Most of the topics online right now are referring to using a box from vagrant cloud, or building one from scratch etc. My issue is I have an already built virtual box using Virtualbox as the provider specifically 1.4.3 as the version. The box is 124GB so remaking it is not exactly ideal. I have the vagrant config file set to locate the virtual box at path /users/desktop/foldername/filename.vbox. Every time it tries to add the box I get the error

```
"The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box file you're trying to add is not corrupted and try again. The output from attemtping to unpackage (if any): 

Bsdtar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format."
```

My knowledge is that this is because Vagrant is looking to add a .tar file and the file is not a tar extension.

Your supposed to be able to configure vagrant file to recognize the provider which I have done as well. Mine is set to

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

But no matter what I try I'm always getting the error above. 
One thing to note is I'm not sure how to go about providing the metadata.json file, or how I can find that to edit it. Perhaps that is my problem? I have the latest version of vagrant so that is not the issue.

### Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried the vagrant package and below is my error I'm getting Please see if you may be able to provide further assistance.

I tried what you have suggested and here is the error message that I'm getting. I greatly appreciate your help.

```
nokeys$  vagrant package --base Dev_Clonea --output /users/nokeys/desktop/Dev_Clone/Dev_Clone.vbox

/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:306:in `id=': undefined method `children' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:438:in `state'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/created.rb:11:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:43:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:196:in `action_raw'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:173:in `block in action'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:434:in `lock'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `call'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `action'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/commands/package/command.rb:83:in `package_vm'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/commands/package/command.rb:66:in `package_base'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/commands/package/command.rb:42:in `execute'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'

from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:252:in `cli'

from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/bin/vagrant:166:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vagrant package --base <name of vm> --output <path>.box
```

Lets say you virtual machine is named 'my_vm' and you want to drop it into the home directory

```
vagrant package --base my_vm --output ~/my_vm.box
```

Vagrant will package your virtual machine into a base box. Whatever you name the box with the output flag, will be the name you use in your vagrantfile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have tried this and I get a new error. I couldn't paste it in this comment so i added it to the top question . Any ideas on what I can try from here ? Thank you for your help

Comment: Off the top of my head I would recomend double checking the name of the VM as the --base argument. Run this command:        `VBoxManage list vms` and make sure that "Dev_Clonea" is on that list. If not, then your problem is that the 'base' argument should be the same name as the VM on that output.

Comment: I see my problem was I made the --base my NEW name, rather than the NEW name being on the -- output so I had it reversed. Its still running however considering its 124 GB.. I will update, and greencheck once i can confirmed it has worked completely. Thanks for the help it seems i'm on the right track since you posted this.

Comment: Glad to hear it! The package command takes a while no matter what, even on my small linux boxes, I could only imagine how long it would take for a VM of that size. Best of luck.

Comment: So the box is up and running. Which i appreciate you have been very helpful. Now however when im ssh'ing into it. It asking for a password. I need to figure out how to set the SSH password. From what i can tell other peoples answers are quite confusing on this subject. Do you have experience with this ?

Comment: By default the password will be "vagrant". There are also ways to set it manually in your vagrantfile, but look into the command: vagrant ssh-config.

Comment: How can I know the name of my VM in Windows? I have Oracle Virtual Box installed on my system. What will be the value of my_vm in my case?